# "No such key 'middle-button-enabled'" When trying to enable middle mouse button following wiki

Tags: 16.04, mouse

In trying to get the middle mouse button to work in 16.04 I followed the instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Quirks#A2-button_Mice). 
I made a file in the correct folder with the correct content, but when I was doing step 3 I got an error:

[image]

Any idea if I am doing anything wrong in the process or if there is something else I can do to get the middle mouse button working?